# Slick slide on scroll is too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to slide through images using slick on scroll, but the problem is the scroll is too fast and sometimes goes through two images at once.

how to slow it down, and make sure it is only firing the second image after the second scroll(so basically one scroll per image)?

Thanks

```
        slider
        .slick({
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            autoplay: false,
            speed: 1000,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.600, -0.280, 0.735, 0.045)'
        });     
      $(window).bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
        //var current = $('.slick-active').attr('data-slick-index');
        if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
            slider.slick('slickPrev');               
        }
        else {

            slider.slick('slickNext');

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you add a working example to highlight the problem please?

Comment: reduce your speed value?

Comment: @D.V.D. – you wouldn't want to reduce a speed "value" if you want to reduce the speed animation, instead increase the value.

Comment: reducing the speed will affect the transition timing only, also will give me a slow transitions between images. the problem is the scroll changes more than one image, reducing the speed will still change more than one image but will do it slower